# Use HyperlinkedModelSerializer in ManyToMany field in Django

Tags: python, django, django-rest-framework

### Scenario

In a project, I have following code.

#### models.py

```
class Section(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(_('Section'), max_length=254, unique=True)
    desc = models.TextField(_('Description'), null=True, blank=True)

class Item(CreateUpdateModel):
    name = models.CharField(_('Name'), max_length=254, unique=True)
    price = models.DecimalField(_('Item Price'), max_digits=10, decimal_places=3)
    sections = models.ManyToManyField(Section)
    desc = models.TextField(_('Description'), null=True, blank=True)
```

#### serializers.py

```
class ShowSectionSerializer(serializers.HyperlinkedModelSerializer):
    item_set = serializers.HyperlinkedIdentityField(view_name='Show Section Items', lookup_url_kwarg='sections',lookup_field='id')

    class Meta:
        from .models import Section

        model = Section
        fields = ('name', 'id', 'desc', 'item_set')


class ShowItemSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    sections = ShowSectionSerializer(many=True)

    class Meta:
        from .models import Item
        model = Item
        fields = ('id', 'name', 'sections', 'desc')
```

#### urls.py

```
path('show/item/section/<int:sections>', views.ShowSectionItemView.as_view(), name='Show Section Items'),
path('show/section/', views.ShowSectionView.as_view(), name='Show Sections'),
path('show/item/', views.ShowItemView.as_view(), name='Show-Item'),
```

#### views.py

```
class ShowItemView(ListAPIView):
    from .models import Item
    from .serializers import ShowItemSerializer
    from django_filters.rest_framework import DjangoFilterBackend
    from rest_framework.filters import SearchFilter
    from .filters import MenuFiltering
    from .paginations import CustomPageSizePagination

    permission_classes = (AllowAny, )
    queryset = Item.objects.all().order_by('id')
    serializer_class = ShowItemSerializer
    filter_backends = (DjangoFilterBackend, SearchFilter)
    pagination_class = CustomPageSizePagination

    filter_class = MenuFiltering
    search_fields = ('^name', '^sections__name')


class ShowSectionItemView(ShowItemView):
    lookup_field = 'sections__id'
    lookup_url_kwarg = 'sections'

    search_fields = ('^name',)

    def get_queryset(self):
        return self.queryset.filter(sections__id=self.kwargs.get('sections'))

class ShowSectionView(ListAPIView):
    from .models import Section
    from .serializers import ShowSectionSerializer
    from django_filters.rest_framework import DjangoFilterBackend
    from .paginations import CustomPageSizePagination
    from .filters import SectionFiltering
    from rest_framework.filters import SearchFilter

    filter_class = SectionFiltering
    pagination_class = CustomPageSizePagination
    permission_classes = (AllowAny, )
    filter_backends = (DjangoFilterBackend, )
    queryset = Section.objects.all().order_by('id')
    serializer_class = ShowSectionSerializer
```

### Problem Statement

I want that in each section, there is a URL like: `item_set: https://..../show/item/section/1/` where `1` is the `Primary Key` of that section. If possible, `item_set: https://..../show/item?section=1` URL will be a lot better. This will show all the items that are in a particular section.

### Error

Right now, I am trying for `https://..../show/item/section/1/` but I am getting the following error:

```
django.core.exceptions.ImproperlyConfigured: Could not resolve URL for hyperlinked relationship using view name "Show Section Items". You may have failed to include the related model in your API, or incorrectly configured the `lookup_field` attribute on this field.
```

What am I doing wrong?